# Wordpress URL and wp_get_attachment_image_src - http vs https

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress settings, the Wordpress URL (which is used for a lot of resource URLs) requires you to hardcode either `http://` or `https://` in the URL. This results in issues with insecure parts being loaded on a secure site or vice versa. How do i handle this?

Example:

```
//The wordpress URL setting (In Settings->General)
http://example.net

//An image source (this is now http://example.net/images/myimage.png)
$imageSource = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "myimage" );

?><img src="<?php echo $imageSource; ?>" .?<?php ... ?>
```

If the user is visiting `https://example.net`, the image will still be loaded from the non-secure "http".

How do I fix this so a site in https loads everything (not just `wp_get_attachment_image_src`) in https and vice-versa?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to just replace the http in the URL string.

```
$imageSource = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "myimage" ); 
$output = preg_replace( "^http:", "https:", $imageSource );
echo $output;
```

You could always add a filter to your required functions (for example: `add_filter( 'template_directory_uri', function( $original )`... to always use SSL.

Comment: Is the only solution to use preg-replace across all code? Why don't Wordpress functions account for the different protocols used to access the site?

Comment: When you make a post, the URL is entered to the db post_content. Its for simplicity in building functions. You would need to approach your function calls differently if you dont want to use preg_replace or apply filters. You would for example get the image id and use // instead of http(s):// in your URL string.

Anyways in short, yes you will need to one way or another replace instances of http:// with https://

Answer (score 13):

This is a [known defect/bug](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15928) in WordPress and is scheduled to be fixed in WP 4.0.

In the meantime, [here is a filter a WP dev posted](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/15928#comment:63) that I've had great success with:

```
function ssl_post_thumbnail_urls($url, $post_id) {

  //Skip file attachments
  if(!wp_attachment_is_image($post_id)) {
    return $url;
  }

  //Correct protocol for https connections
  list($protocol, $uri) = explode('://', $url, 2);

  if(is_ssl()) {
    if('http' == $protocol) {
      $protocol = 'https';
    }
  } else {
    if('https' == $protocol) {
      $protocol = 'http';
    }
  }

  return $protocol.'://'.$uri;
}
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_url', 'ssl_post_thumbnail_urls', 10, 2);
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could create a filter for that function

Comment: @cfx has the best answer, it both addresses why this is a problem and a really simple and generalized solution for the problem. I just implemented it today and it was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: @cfx glad you found my little filter useful!

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate on @Epik answer - We should be serving an HTTP when HTTP and HTTPS when HTTPS.

We can add some logic that will check using the built in Wordpress function is_ssl() and then either do the preg replace or use the standard http.

```
    $imageSource = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), "myimage" ); 

    $output = is_ssl() ? preg_replace( "^http:", "https:", $imageSource ) : $imageSource ;
    echo $output;
```